# Boxes Wont Expand On High Resolutions

Tags: html, css

I have a site below which im using the [Golden Grid System](http://goldengridsystem.com/).

But when i scroll to a higher resolution lets say around 1920 the top two boxes get really small.

They stay proportional to the bottom 3 until i hit a high resolution. Youll only see this if you probably have a high resolution set up. But i included images below as examples.

How can i make it so the top two images dont get small when i hit 1920 for no reason.

Here is the . [Link to my site](http://syndicatebox.com/helpout/) so you can see an example.

Thanks! I cant figure this out..

Below 1920
[image: Below 1920]

At 1920
[image: At 1920]

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this from your css!

```
@media screen and (min-width: 117em)
#twoway .wrapper:first-child {
margin-left: 25%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 117em)
#twoway .wrapper {
width: 25%;
}
```